# Is it possible to reference a specific property from spring boot application.properties in an external property file

Tags: spring-boot

In spring boot I have an `application.properties` file in which I have a property 
`apple = X`.
I have another custom property file `Custom.properties`. I want to reference apple in this custom property file so I have this:
`orange = ${spring.apple}`. 
But this does not work at runtime.
Is there any way to get access to an `application.properties` property from another custom properties file?

Edit:
I also tried `orange=${apple}`, that does not work either. I set `spring.config.location` to point to the directory that has `application.properties` and my `custom.properties` file also. I assumed spring boot would load any properties files it sees in `spring.config.location` but looks like it does not. 
Is there any way to load my `custom.properties` file in addition to `application.properties`?

Comment: And why should that work. You have a property named `apple` and try to obtain it through `${spring.apple}`. Which basically looks for a property named `spring.apple` which obviously isn't there. Just reference the property

Comment: I referenced just the property also, that doesn't work either.

Comment: Then how are you loading that properties file?

Comment: I set the spring.config.location to point to the directory that has the application.properties and custom.properties files. It seems like spring boot ignores other properties files in that directory.

Comment: Well yes as it by default only loads `application.properties`. How are you loading the `custom.properties`? Please add it to your question and not as comments.

Comment: Added an edit just now M. Deinum.

Comment: Just add a `@PropertySource`.